# Python cannot import zmq even after installing pyzmq

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I installed `zmq` and `pyzmq` on ubuntu 10.10 and everything went fine.

On **`import zmq`** I get an error,

stating "**`ImportError: cannot import name initthreads`**"

Can anyone tell me **why** is this happening?

Comment: You'll have to find out what module `initthreads` is being imported from. Include the actual traceback in your question.

Comment: Maverick (Ubuntu 10.10) does not include a `python-zmq` package; how did you install them?

Comment: i downloaded the source and compiled them and installed

Comment: its imported from "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/zmq/__init__.py"

Answer (score 4):

Are you having a similar problem to this?

https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/80

The guy is importing it inside the pyzmq directory.

Comment: yes it is the problem. but for me even if i import outside pyzmq folder . it gives me the above error.

Comment: what is "--inplace" build referred in that link above?

Comment: its working i had to run "python setup.py build_ext --inplace" command

Comment: This was my problem as well. Running within the pyzmq build directory put the Python search path out of sorts.

Answer (score -1):

Immediately after activating the `virtualenv`, try

```
pip install pyzmq --install-option="--zmq=bundled"
```

This solved a very similar problem I was having.